# pg_dump creates a lot of pg_catalog statements

Tags: postgresql

I have a complex relational database hosted in 9.4.24 which does not use any dbms specific features like functions. Some tables contain binary columns and there are indexes used. Whenever I dump the database via:

`pg_dump --no-acl --no-privileges --no-owner xy`

Following statements are created bloating the whole dump:

```
 --
 -- Name: 16714; Type: BLOB; Schema: -; Owner: -
 --
* SELECT pg_catalog.lo_create('16714');
```

I have checked the man page for any exclusion possibilities but did not find any switches. What are these statements good for and is it possible to omit these?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can be more specific on your dump, like explicitly listing the schemas you want to dump (which should omit things related to pg_catalog) or you can skip blobs if you don't use blobs.

-n flag to name schemas while -B excludes large objects

```
-n schema1,schema2,..

-B
```

Comment: The dump never contains data from `pg_catalog` - the reference to that schema is only there to make sure that the built-in function `lo_create()` is used and not a user-defined function that is available in the search path

Comment: But the answer is good, because restricting the dump to a schema will skip large objects.

Answer (score 0):

Those are [large objects](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/largeobjects.html).

If you don't need or want them in the dump, use `--no-blobs`.

Comment: Why are these blobs  not located in the standard tables space? Of course I want to dump the data being consistent and not lose any data during a dump.

Comment: Because large objects are stored in a completely different way. And they are not stored in "pg_catalog" if that is what you are thinking. The function `lo_export()` is simply defined in that schema, and using a fully qualified name makes sure that when you run the generated SQL script it uses the built-in function